# Using powershell to copy files from one locaiton to another (combine output files of same name)

Tags: copy, export, concatenation

My experience : 1/10 (first scripting in 15 years)

Background: I have a chat log file that's running actively and eternally. I setup a Powershell command to export the log files to a shared location in another folder. There are multiple log files in the main folder. For ease I've got the entire folder set to export using a wild card command. The original log files I do not have direct access to and are set to clear every 24 hours. I need to go back further than 24 hours occasionally to an unknown time frame that might be several days earlier. The current export is simply replacing the existing output files with the new output files allowing me to go only 24 hours back.
Desire: I need to combine the copied files in the new location to the previous export that put them there, instead of overwriting them (and instead of adding a new filename, ie filename and filename1) or essentially concatenate the files into one by the same existing filename

Where I'm at:

- Ive created the Powershell file;

  ```
  Copy-Item "C:\Users\Soutinwyze\AppData\Roaming\HexChat\logs\Our_Secrets\*.*" "C:\Users\Soutinwyze\Dropbox\Public\hexchat logs"
  ```
- Ive created a bat file;

  ```
  PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""c:\scripts\hexchat.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
  ```
- Ive created a windows task that runs the bat file every day

What I need: combine output files/syntax

Comment: i see theres the "cat file1 file2 | sort > file3" command but then i have to create a script for each channel or log file and cant use my wildcard command.
also, its not ideal to have some of the information in the first text file duplicated. if i get the first hurdle solved, the next step would be to not copy any of the data that already exists in the output folder large version of the log file.

Comment: sorry unable to edit existing post, it seems i may be running into issues using version 2 of powershell, i have netframework 4.7.1 and it doesnt have v4, and i get errors when trying to install any version higher than my current. ( will seek other threads until i can resolve my version issue before revisiting my cat commands

Comment: got updated to verison 5 and issue persist, i cant seem to run the cat command without getting an error like: Get-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\Scripts\output\granny test log.txt'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Cat "C:\Scripts\granny test log.txt" "C:\Scripts\output\granny test l ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Comment: decided to go with an export to a new folder by the date name for ease;
$basedir = "$env:C:\path\logs"
$today   = (Get-Date).ToString('dd_MM_yy')

$location = New-Item -Path $basedir -Type Directory -Name $today

Copy-Item 'C:\end path desired' -Destination $location